# Form data to  wordpress DB

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am looking for ANY plugin which can save custom form(newsletter form, contact form) data to WP database (front-end) and then allow to browse the submitted data in the back-end (WP admin).

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solutions would be:

**Contact Form 7:** http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ 
**Contact Form to DB:** http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/

Contact Form 7 to Database Extension:

- export all of the data to DB
- allows browsing and exporting
- keeps every form data separate to browse/export

Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ can do front-end forms: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/tutorials/creating-a-front-end-form/

as well as http://www.gravityforms.com/ which is a commercial plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With this plugin you can add PHP code to your pages that saves form data to a  database.

https://woodysnippet.com/getting-started-with-woody-ad-snippets/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).